# Complex SQL query suggestions please

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with schema as below:

Table: **Apps**

```
| ID (bigint) | USERID (Bigint)|      START_TIME (datetime) | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        13     |         2013-05-03 04:42:55 | 
|  2          |        13     |         2013-05-12 06:22:45 |
|  3          |        13     |         2013-06-12 08:44:24 |    
|  4          |        13     |         2013-06-24 04:20:56 |       
|  5          |        13     |         2013-06-26 08:20:26 |       
|  6          |        13     |         2013-09-12 05:48:27 |
```

Table: **Hosts**

```
| ID (bigint) | APPID (Bigint)|         DEVICE_ID (Bigint)  | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        1      |                           1 | 
|  2          |        2      |                           1 |
|  3          |        1      |                           1 |    
|  4          |        3      |                           3 |       
|  5          |        1      |                           4 |      
|  6          |        2      |                           3 |
```

Table:  **Usage**

```
| ID (bigint) | APPID (Bigint)|             HOSTID (Bigint) |   Factor (varchar)    |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        1      |                           1 |               Low     | 
|  2          |        1      |                           3 |               High    | 
|  3          |        2      |                           2 |               Low     | 
|  4          |        3      |                           4 |               Medium  | 
|  5          |        1      |                           5 |               Low     | 
|  6          |        2      |                           2 |               Medium  |
```

Now if put is userid, i want to get the **count of rows of table rows for each month (of all app) for each "Factor" month wise for the last 6 months**.

If a DEVICE_ID appears more than once in a month (based on START_TIME, based on joining Apps and Hosts), only the latest rows of Usage (based on combination of Apps, Hosts and Usage) be considered for calculating count.

**Example output of the query for the above example should be:** (for input user id=13)

```
| MONTH       | USAGE_COUNT   |               FACTOR        | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  5          |        0      |                 High        | 
|  6          |        0      |                 High        | 
|  7          |        0      |                 High        | 
|  8          |        0      |                 High        |       
|  9          |        0      |                 High        |       
|  10         |        0      |                 High        | 
|  5          |        2      |                 Low         | 
|  6          |        0      |                 Low         | 
|  7          |        0      |                 Low         | 
|  8          |        0      |                 Low         |       
|  9          |        0      |                 Low         |       
|  10         |        0      |                 Low         |
|  5          |        1      |                 Medium      | 
|  6          |        1      |                 Medium      | 
|  7          |        0      |                 Medium      | 
|  8          |        0      |                 Medium      |       
|  9          |        0      |                 Medium      |       
|  10         |        0      |                 Medium      |
```

**How is this calculated?**

1. For Month May 2013 (05-2013), there are two Apps from table Apps
2. In table Hosts , these apps are associated with device_id's 1,1,1,4,3
3. For this month (05-2013) for device_id=1, the latest value of start_time is:  2013-05-12 06:22:45 (from tables hosts,apps), so in table Usage, look for combination of appid=2&hostid=2 for which there are two rows one with factor Low and other Medium,
4. For this month (05-2013) for device_id=4, by following same procedure we get one entry i.e 0 Low
5. Similarly all the values are calculated.

To get the last 6 months via query i'm trying to get it with the following:

```
SELECT MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL aInt MONTH)) AS aMonth
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 0 AS aInt UNION SELECT -1 UNION SELECT -2 UNION SELECT -3 UNION SELECT -4 UNION SELECT -5
    )
```

Please check sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55fc2

Comment: You may need to edit to clarify this question. My answer and @ubik404 both could be valid depending on exactly what behavior you want.

Comment: @Dan I can see only your answer. I am testing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the calculation you're doing involves the same join multiple times, I started by creating a view.

```
CREATE VIEW `app_host_usage`
AS 
SELECT a.id "appid", h.id "hostid", u.id "usageid",
       a.userid, a.start_time, h.device_id, u.factor
  FROM apps a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hosts h ON h.appid = a.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `usage` u ON u.appid = a.id AND u.hostid = h.id
  WHERE a.start_time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 MONTH)
```

The `WHERE` condition is there because I made the assumption that you don't want July 2005 and July 2006 to be grouped together in the same count.

With that view in place, the query becomes

```
SELECT months.Month, COUNT(DISTINCT device_id), factors.factor
FROM
  (
    -- Get the last six months
    SELECT (MONTH(NOW()) + aInt + 11) % 12 + 1 "Month" FROM
      (SELECT 0 AS aInt UNION SELECT -1 UNION SELECT -2 UNION SELECT -3 UNION SELECT -4 UNION SELECT -5) LastSix
  ) months
  JOIN
  ( 
    -- Get all known factors
    SELECT DISTINCT factor FROM `usage` 
  ) factors
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    -- Get factors for each device... 
    SELECT 
           MONTH(start_time) "Month", 
           device_id,
           factor
      FROM app_host_usage a
      WHERE userid=13 
        AND start_time IN (
          -- ...where the corresponding usage row is connected
          --    to an app row with the highest start time of the
          --    month for that device.
          SELECT MAX(start_time)
            FROM app_host_usage a2
            WHERE a2.device_id = a.device_id
            GROUP BY MONTH(start_time)
        )
     GROUP BY MONTH(start_time), device_id, factor

  ) usageids ON usageids.Month = months.Month 
            AND usageids.factor = factors.factor
GROUP BY factors.factor, months.Month
ORDER BY factors.factor, months.Month
```

which is insanely complicated, but I've tried to comment explaining what each part does. See this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c871/1/0

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. I'm testing the query.

Comment: @Dan I wanted to count usage time for distinct devices each month, but this query gives me count of devices, can you please help?

Comment: @sash Not without a clearer understanding of what you're looking for. There are too many ways to interpret your requirements. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c871/13 is one possibility.